# Statistical test for changes in ranks

Tags: hypothesis-testing, ranking, ranks

I am investigating changes in rankings of schools.  For example, in year $t$ school X may have been in the 17th percentile (poor performer) but in year $t+1$ it may have improved to be in the 94th percentile (high performer), a change of +77 percentile points. To determine if this change is larger than you may expect I could take all the changes for each school over a number of years, fit a normal distribution (if appropriate) and then find the probability of obtaining a change at least as large a 77 percentile points from this distribution.

My question is whether the above is appropriate or whether there is a more appropriate (possibly non-parametric) test I should use?